# Como gerar várias colunas numa query a partir de apenas uma coluna?

Tags: mysql

Preciso de uma Query que retorne 2 colunas somadas (entrada e saida) a partir da coluna "contabil" da tabela "tbl_sef". o Valor da coluna "contabil" será da coluna "entrada" quando a coluna "cfop" for menor que 5000. E será da coluna "saida" quando o valor da coluna "cfop" for maior ou igual que 5000.

tbl_sef:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O retorno que ideal seria:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei de várias formas e não consegui!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize a função de agregração `SUM` em conjunto com a estrutura `CASE`:

```
SELECT inscricao,
       SUM(CASE WHEN cfop < 5000 THEN contabil ELSE 0 END) AS entrada,
       SUM(CASE WHEN cfop >= 5000 THEN contabil ELSE 0 END) AS saida
  FROM tbl_sef
 GROUP BY inscricao
```

---

> [`GROUP BY Modifiers`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)
>
> The `GROUP BY` clause permits a `WITH ROLLUP` modifier that causes summary output to include extra rows that represent higher-level (that is, super-aggregate) summary operations. `ROLLUP` thus enables you to answer questions at multiple levels of analysis with a single query. For example, `ROLLUP` can be used to provide support for `OLAP (Online Analytical Processing)` operations.
>
> Suppose that a sales table has year, country, product, and profit columns for recording sales profitability:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE sales(
>   year    INT,
>   country VARCHAR(20),
>   product VARCHAR(32),
>   profit  INT
> );
> ```
>
> To summarize table contents per year, use a simple `GROUP BY` like this:
>
> ```
> SELECT year, SUM(profit) AS profit
>   FROM sales
>  GROUP BY year;
>
> +------+--------+
> | year | profit |
> +------+--------+
> | 2000 |   4525 |
> | 2001 |   3010 |
> +------+--------+
> ```

Em tradução livre:

> A cláusula `GROUP BY` permite um modificador`WITH ROLLUP` que faz com que a saída de resumo inclua linhas extras que representam operações de resumo de nível superior (isto é, super agregadas). O `ROLLUP` permite-lhe responder a questões em múltiplos níveis de análise com uma única consulta. Por exemplo, `ROLLUP` pode ser usado para fornecer suporte para operações`OLAP (Online Analytical Processing)`.
>
> Suponha que uma tabela de vendas tenha colunas de ano, país, produto e lucro para registrar a lucratividade das vendas:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE sales(
>   year    INT,
>   country VARCHAR(20),
>   product VARCHAR(32),
>   profit  INT
> );
> ```
>
> Para resumir o conteúdo da tabela por ano, use um `GROUP BY` simples assim:
>
> ```
> SELECT year, SUM(profit) AS profit
>   FROM sales
>  GROUP BY year;
>
> +------+--------+
> | year | profit |
> +------+--------+
> | 2000 |   4525 |
> | 2001 |   3010 |
> +------+--------+
> ```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou! vc tem algum material em .PDF?

Comment: @JamersonCavalcanti Na realidade não tenho, mas você acha bastante tutorial na internet. Não esqueça de aceitar a resposta como escolhida para que outras pessoas possam se beneficiar da solução

Comment: blz, obrigado!!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o CASE para seprar com o SUM para somar:

```
select
    tbl_sef.incricao,
    SUM(case
        when tbl_sef.cfop < 5000 then tbl_sef.contabil
    end case) as Entrada,
    SUM(case
        when tbl_sef.cfop >= 5000 then tbl_sef.contabil
    end case) as Saida
from
    tbl_sef
```